# What can we conclude if $\mathcal{N}$ is an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$?

Tags: model-theory

In particular, if $\mathcal{N}$ is an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$, can we immediately conclude that if $\mathcal{M} \models T$, then $\mathcal{N} \models T$? Why or why not?

**My line of reasoning**

We have for all $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi$, $\forall \bar{a} \in \mathbb{M}$ and its interpretation in $\mathcal{N}$ $\pmb{k}(\bar{a})$:
    $$\mathcal{M} \models \phi(\bar{a}) \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{N} \models\phi(\pmb{k}(\bar{a})).$$

Let $T$ be comprised of such $\phi$'s, then we have $\mathcal{N} \models T$ as desired.

**Update**

My question is a more general version of this question, which gives more context about what $T$ is.

Suppose $T$ has $\forall\exists$-axiomatization, $(\mathbb{I},<)$ is a linear order, and $(\mathcal{M}_i : i \in \mathbb{I})$ is a chain of models of $T$. We show that $\bigcup \mathcal{M}_i$ is a model of $T$.

Comment: @RobArthan I reasoned this is immediate as well, but as a novice I don't trust anything I think.

Comment: Excuse me! The comment I just deleted wasn't helpful. What is $T$?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly my problem, I updated the question with my proof, stating what $T$ is. Please check to make sure it's sound?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: @RobArthan sorry didn't know you'd respond so quickly!

Comment: Don't you have any context that defines $T$. I was guessing that it would be a set of sentences in the language in question (no parameters, no free variables). In that case your proof is right (and can be simplified because $\overline{a}$ can be taken to be empty).

Comment: Well the question I am trying to answer states: "Suppose $T$ has a $\forall\exists$-axiomatization, $(\mathbb{I},<)$ is a linear order, and $(\mathcal{M}_i : i \in \mathbb{I})$ is a chain of models of $\T$. We show that $\bigcup \mathcal{M}_i$ is a model of $T$". So $T$ is given in this context. I generalized the question a bit. But how will the context play in here?

Comment: Yes, so in this context $T$ will indeed be a set of sentences not involving parameters from the models, and my comment above applies. (By "context", I just meant the source of the question.) Get rid of $\overline{a}$ and you have answered your own question.

Comment: @RobArthan can I ask were you able to conclude $T$ does not have parameters from the models? Furthermore, since $M = \bigcup M_i$ and it's an elementary extension, wouldn't parameters such as $\bar{a}$ have an interpretation in $\mathcal{M}$ as well?

Comment: It's just the logic of the original problem. $T$ is a set of sentences and the ${\cal M}_i$ are models for that set of sentences: $T$ came first so it doesn't make sense for it to include parameters drawn from the ${\cal M}_i$.